# regex to replace "<p><br/></p>" string with empty string- Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have some HTML as a string

```
var str= "<p><br/></p>"
```

How do I strip the p tags from this string using JS.
here is what I have tried so far:

```
str.replace(/<p[^>]*>(?:\s|&nbsp;)*<\/p>/, "") // o/p: <p><br></p>'
str.replace("/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/", "")// o/p: <p><br></p>'
str.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/g, "")// o/p: <p><br></p>'
```

all of them return me same str as above, expected o/p is:
str should be `""`
what im doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you prevent the offending string from being added to the HTML so that you don't need to try removing it?

Comment: I'm using React Quill component and that component adds this value, I am not sure if I can prevent without touching the component. at this point my best shot is to remove the empty tags and <br/> tag

Comment: May be you should screen all arrows `\<` and `\>`

Comment: regex is preferred, but if regex does not work,anythign would do

Comment: In the last replace, aren't you missing the / in <br/>?

Comment: yeah, tried that too `str.replaceAll("/<p><br/><\/p>/g", "");`- didnt work

Comment: why you don't use normal string replace, without regex

Comment: But that is not an _empty_ <p> tag.  It has a <br/> tag in it.  ??

Comment: the outcome should have no tags in it- shoudl be `""` string

Comment: I'm saying it's just as important to define for us what should *not* be removed as what *should* be removed.  One example of input and expected output tells us almost nothing - especially when supported by contradictory text explanation of it being an _empty_ tag (it's not).  Define the problem better please.

Comment: @user1234 in your `replaceAll()` you used quotes, regexes should be without quotes

Comment: str = str.replace(/<p.*?><(\w+)\/?>(<\/\1>)?<\/p>/g, '')
str = str.replace(/<p.*?>&nbsp;<\/p>/g, '')
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should not be using RegExp to parse HTML - it's not particularly useful with (X)HTML-style markup as [there are way too many edge cases.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/269970)

Instead, parse the HTML as you would an element in the DOM, then compare the `trim()`med `innerText` value of each `<p>` with a blank string, and remove those that are equal:

```js
var str = "<p><br/></p><p>This paragraph has text</p>"
var ele = document.createElement('body');
ele.innerHTML = str;
[...ele.querySelectorAll('p')].forEach(para => {
  if (para.innerText.trim() === "") ele.removeChild(para);
});

console.log(ele.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following expression: `<p[^>]*>(&nbsp;|\s+|<br\s*\/?>)*<\/p>`

The expression above looks at expressions enclosed in `<p>...</p>` and matches them against `&nbsp;`, whitespace (`\s+`) and `<br>` (and `/` variations).

I think you were mostly there with `/<p[^>]*>(?:\s|&nbsp;)*<\/p>/`, but you just needed to remove `?:` (not sure what you were trying to do here), and adding an additional case for `<br>`.

```js
const str = `
<p><br></p>
<p><br/></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p> <br/> </p>
<p> </p>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<p><br/> &nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p><!-- multiline -->
<p><br/> don't replace me</p>
<p>don't replace me</p>
`;

const exp = /<p[^>]*>(&nbsp;|\s+|<br\s*\/?>)*<\/p>/g;

console.log(str.replace(exp, ''));
```